# Chrome issue: blurry text, sticky position and mobile devices

Tags: css, sticky

Help please! I have blurry text on sticky div on mobile devices.
Here's css:

```
.sticky-panel {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 3;  
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;  
}
```

What I tried and it didn't help me:

1) `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

2) `transform: translateZ(0);`

3) `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

4) `-webkit-filter: blur(0.000001px);`

Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmt309qv/

How it looks like:

[image]

But it's ok when div reaches bottom of the document. Did anyone have such problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the CSS you provided.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a bit late, but I have encouter the same problem, after some research I found workaround from [webkit bug tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159428)

> I am able to overcome/workaround the bug on the actual site by forcing the container to have a `top` or `height` that is a whole number.

For case when content is changing it's size is a bit problematic.

#### Workaround/Solution

```
.sticky-panel {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 3;  
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;
  top: 0px; // <-- set number of pixels for top
  height: 100px; // or set number of pixels for height
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me by use transform : translateX(1%)

```
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    transform: translateX(1%); //Make Text is not blurry
```